# proof by induction: logarithms

Tags: algorithms, induction, proof-explanation

The Question: " An algorithm is known to have a complexity $T_{N}=O\left(\frac{N}{2}(\lg N)^2\right)$ with an additional
correction proportional to $N \lg N$ where the lg designates the binary logarithm here.

(a) The recurrence relation is $T_{2N}= 2 ( T_{N} + N\lg N)$ and starts with $T_N=0$ for $N=2.$
Write down a table from which you derive a hypothesis for the exact $T_N.$

(b) Prove your hypothesis by induction."

i have this problem at my Algorithms exam, i tried it several hours but what i found for $T_N$ did not go along with the basic formula provided, what i got for $T_N$ is $T_{N}= N(\lg N)^2 + N\lg N$, these logarithms is base 2 of course.

i hope you can help me

Comment: Please check your work. The formula you got does not match my spreadsheet values. If you cannot find your mistake, edit the question to show how you got the first few values of $T_N$ (perhaps just $T_2, T_4, T_8$), how you derived your formula, and how you evaluate your formula at each such $N.$

Comment: Note that your formula, $2(T_N + N\lg N),$ is $O\left(\frac N2(\lg N)^2\right)$ (because $O\left(\frac N2(\lg N)^2\right)$ is the same as $O\left(2N(\lg N)^2\right)$), and it has an "additional correction" proportional to $N\lg N.$ It exactly satisfies the conditions given in the problem statement; it just doesn't give results anywhere near the correct values.

Answer (score 0):

Hint 1:

Since you can only calculate $T_N$ when $N$ is a power of $2$, define $$a_n = T_{2^n}$$Then your recursion becomes $a_{n+1} = 2(a_n +n2^n)$.

Hint 2:

> Then consider defining $b_n = \dfrac{a_n}{2^n}$, so $a_n = 2^nb_n$.